Why does my Playwright webscraping app timeout when deployed on Render but not locally?
I have a relatively simple web-scraping app that mostly uses Beautiful Soup, but for the dynamically loaded sites, I have been using Playwright, and love it... when it works.
I have containerized my app with docker and the container works locally as well, including the two playwright routes. But still no luck when deployed on render even when I set the timeout to 60000 ms.
TLDR: can't escape the timeout error on my playwright routes.
Here is the main error from my render logs:
playwright._impl._errors.TimeoutError: Timeout 60000ms exceeded.
Here is the beginning to one of the flask routes that times out when deployed:
 def eulogy():
     url = 'https://burialbeer.com/pages/eulogy'
     with sync_playwright() as p:
         browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
         context = browser.new_context(user_agent=headers['User-Agent'])
         page = context.new_page() 
         page.goto(url, timeout=60000).  #TIME OUT OCCURS RIGHT HERE
         ageVerificationBtn = 'button[name="confirm-age"]'...

.```


For me this worked:
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True,
                args=[
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                    '--no-zygote',
                    '--single-process']) 

Adding the args array helped. I'm not sure which one, but now the app works when deployed as well as locally.
